# Allow users to ask many questions in one question text

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I’m wishing this change because I have many questions about Christianity. I want to understand the concept of trinity, because myself I can’t explain. I have questions about Christianity.

Can you please make this change? Like I ask, “I have some questions about Christianity”

And then to list only 5 questions in question text.

Answer (score 6):

This site is a bit different from others, and has a different focus than general reference sites, like Wikipedia, and discussion sites, like Reddit and other forums.

Instead, we are a Q&A site, where we attempt to communicate bite-sized pieces of information that directly deals with specific, objective questions.

In your situation, it sounds like you would benefit from reviewing general reference sites like Wikipedia to learn about your high-level topics.  You can also review the sources that Wikipedia cites, to get more details.  Often, questions that come out of such research are good things to ask about here.

And when you do have multiple, focused questions, please ask them as separate questions.  This makes them easier to answer, and it also keeps the information organized so that future readers can find specifically what they are looking for.